# How can I update shown dialog imageview with selected image?

Tags: android, dialog

I am using Alert dialog for getting Image for User team pic and then I want to show image preview on dialog which is already open.

I am passing image file to that fragment where my dialog is shown but how I can update that `ImageView` which is in dialog I tried to update adapter by which I can notify data but still I am getting null adapter after having call on that fragment

```
  public void passingImage(Image image) {
    testAdapter.notifyImage(image);
}
```

this is my Alert dialog code

```
public void showDialogForTeam(ChallengeData mData) {
    this.mData = mData;
    dialogForTeam = new Dialog(activity);
    dialogForTeam.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialogForTeam.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_team_selection);
    dialogForTeam.setTitle("Select Team");
    spinner = (Spinner) dialogForTeam.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    imgClose = (ImageView) dialogForTeam.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager5 = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rvLogo = (RecyclerView) dialogForTeam.findViewById(R.id.rv_logo);
    rvLogo.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rvLogo.setLayoutManager(layoutManager5);

    rvLogo.setAdapter(testAdapter);
    btnUpload = (TextView) dialogForTeam.findViewById(R.id.btn_upload_icon);
    tealLogo = (ImageView) dialogForTeam.findViewById(R.id.team_logo);


    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                openGallery();

            } else {
                Nammu.askForPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, new PermissionCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void permissionGranted() {
                        openGallery();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void permissionRefused() {

                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });
    GridView gridView = (GridView) dialogForTeam.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(activity, this));
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) dialogForTeam.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    final LinearLayout llMyteam = (LinearLayout) dialogForTeam.findViewById(R.id.ll_m_team);
    final RecyclerView recyclerViewTeam = (RecyclerView) dialogForTeam.findViewById(R.id.rv_team);
    String[] strings = new String[0];
    if (mData.getIsTeamcreater().equals("true")) {
        strings = new String[]{"Join as Team Member", "Create Team"};
    } else
        strings = new String[]{"Join as Team Member"};
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(activity, R.layout.row_simple_text, strings));
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("Join as Team Member")) {
                llMyteam.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                recyclerViewTeam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                llMyteam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recyclerViewTeam.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(activity, R.layout.row_simple_text, strings));
    if (mData.getTeams() != null && mData.getTeams().size() > 0) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager4 = new LinearLayoutManager(activity);
        recyclerViewTeam.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewTeam.setLayoutManager(layoutManager4);
        JoinTeamChallengeAdapter allTeamAdapter = new JoinTeamChallengeAdapter(activity, mData.getTeams(), this);
        recyclerViewTeam.setAdapter(allTeamAdapter);
    }

    imgClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialogForTeam.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialogForTeam.show();

}

public void openGallery() {
    ImagePicker.create(activity)
            .folderMode(true) // folder mode (false by default)
            .folderTitle("Folder") // folder selection title
            .imageTitle("Tap to select") // image selection title
            .single() // single mode
            .limit(1) // max images can be selected (99 by default)
            .showCamera(true) // show camera or not (true by default)
            .imageDirectory("Camera") // directory name for captured image  ("Camera" folder by default)
            .start(9686); // start image picker activity with request code
}
```

MianActivity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult    :" + requestCode);
    if (requestCode == 9686) {
        ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_SELECTED_IMAGES);
        if (images.size() > 0 && images.size() == 1){
            image = images.get(0);
            mainHomeFragment.passingImage(image);
        }

    } else if (requestCode == 9687) {
        ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_SELECTED_IMAGES);
        if (images.size() > 0 && images.size() == 1)
            onPhotoReturned(images.get(0));
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the [Android Developer Page](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPhotoView) under the Point Get the Thumbnail is a Example which shows how to add a Photo in a existing ImageView of the Activity after Capturing it with an Intent. I hope it is what you are looking for.

**EDIT:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

As you see, you can change a Image view through the command `setImageBitmap(image)` which needs a Bitmap. If that is not helping you, try to look at the Api of [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)

Comment: I want to show on dialog imageview and dialog already on view

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13794831)

Comment: Changed and add the essential Code from the Page thanks for the Advice @AdityaVyas-Lakhan

Comment: I already got the Image object in 'OnActivityResult' but the question is that how i can show image on already opened dialog ... i passed the object from main to fragment where my dialog is available but after resume of fragment i am not able to access that image object ... And please if you don't understand the question don't try to answer in general way... I knew the link shared ....@Vincentthe0ne

Comment: Is this all of your testAdapter in your Question? Or do you have more code for it? And when you resume the fragment "not able to access it" means that your image points to null?